# Cannot get @Transactional and Hibernate 4 to work together

Tags: hibernate, spring-transactions

I'm trying to get Hibernate 4 and Spring Transactions to play together.  At this point, I'm just trying to get a Hibernate setup that works.

Here's the method called.  When I call it, I get

```
"org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction"



@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Transactional
public SecurityUserDO findSecurityUser(String email)
{
    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

    Query query = session.createQuery( "from SecurityUserDO where email = :email" );
    query.setString( "email", email );
    return (SecurityUserDO) query.uniqueResult();
}
```

Here's the config:

```
<!-- use annotations to find beans in this package -->
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.jelli.phoenix.model" />

<!--  Default session factory. Requires a dataSource bean to be defined in another config.
This works with a embedded data source for integration test setup. For real deployment
the datasource should be a c3p0 pool. -->
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean" autowire="byName"
     depends-on="dataSource">
    <property name="configLocation">    
        <value>
            classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>

            <!-- Database connection settings --> 
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>

            <!-- Caching -->
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</prop>

            <!-- Performance Settings --> 
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_versioned_data">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">1</prop>

            <!-- When SQL is logged, pretty-print it --> 
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>

<!-- Use @Transaction annotations for managing transactions  -->    
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
```

The datasource is specified in another file.

I've read every post I could find on this.  Several said to remove the

```
"&lt;prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class"&gt;thread&lt;/prop&gt;",
```

but that causes the `getCurrentSession()` to fail.

Comment: Is findSecurityUser in a service?  Are you using context:component scan on your service package in your config?

Comment: how are you calling findSecurityUser, and how are you getting the bean that contains that method?

Comment: So, have you removed the property you were told to remove? What happened?

Comment: The class containing findSecurityUser is a @Service and there is a context:component scan.  Here is the calling code:

    public void testFindSecurityUserSuccess()
    {
        SecurityUserDO user = securityDAO.findSecurityUser( "1@test.com" );
        assertNotNull( user );
        assertEquals( user.getEmail(), "1@test.com" );
    }

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

The issue, as outlined many other places, is that I had:

<prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</prop>

This disables Spring Transactions, but creates a problem in that SessionFactory.getCurrentSession() no longer works.  My workaround is to write a utility class that calls SessionFactory.openSession() and saves the session in ThreadLocal.

I have to say I really don't understand why Spring Transactions refuse to play with Hibernate's thread-based session context.